# MySQL check if an IP-address is in range?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains two columns `ipStart` and `ipEnd`

These two fields contain a range of ip address. For example:

```
`ipStart` = 193.235.18.0
```

and

```
ipEnd = 193.235.21.255
```

I want to be able to select the row with an ip that is within the range, for example:

```
193.235.19.255
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I wouldn't do this in SQL. Do it in your fav. programming language which is the better way.

Comment: have you tried between ? SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE Price BETWEEN 10 AND 20;

Comment: @cb0 so you go over all mysql rows in the program?

Comment: @cb0 doing this in an application would mean retrieving the whole table every time. If the table is big, that is a problem.

Answer (score 24):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE (INET_ATON("193.235.19.255") BETWEEN INET_ATON(ipStart) AND INET_ATON(ipEnd));
```

Comment: How "heavy" would this be on a database containing over 60 mil records?

Comment: Very heavy since no index will be used. Better to have IPs as numerical values in the DB, then create an index on them.

Comment: So I would store: 193.235.18.0 as this: 193235180 ?

Comment: No. Use the INET_ATON() function to do the conversion. It is effectively (a*256^3)+(b*256^2)+(c*256)+d.

Comment: @alosylus: No, not like that. It would be better to convert the IPs with the `INET_ATON()` function to a `BIGINT` and store the `ipSstart` and `ipEnd` as bigints.

Comment: nice one. never heard about this one! :D *thumbs_up*

Comment: But this will always be at least as slow as a full table table scan. If you want to use indexes to speed up the queries you need tuse spatial indexes - https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/using-mysql-spatial-extensions-for-range-queries/

Comment: What about IPv6 addresses?

Answer (score 7):

To explain converting an ip address to a number which a few answers have relied on (and which I agree with).

The ip address needs to be treated as one 32 bit number rather than 4 8 bit numbers

For example the ip address

193.235.18.0

converted to binary is:-

11000001.11101011.00010010.00000000

Which you translate into (ie, take the dots out):-

11000001111010110001001000000000

Working that out you get:-

```
1 * 2147483648 = 2147483648 
1 * 1073741824 = 1073741824 
0 * 536870912 = 0
0 * 268435456 = 0
0 * 134217728 = 0
0 * 67108864 = 0
0 * 33554432 = 0
1 * 16777216 = 16777216 
1 * 8388608 = 8388608 
1 * 4194304 = 4194304 
1 * 2097152 = 2097152 
0 * 1048576 = 0
1 * 524288 = 524288 
0 * 262144 = 0
1 * 131072 = 131072 
1 * 65536 = 65536 
0 * 32768 = 0
0 * 16384 = 0
0 * 8192 = 0
1 * 4096 = 4096 
0 * 2048 = 0
0 * 1024 = 0
1 * 512 = 512 
0 * 256 = 0
0 * 128 = 0
0 * 64 = 0
0 * 32 = 0
0 * 16 = 0
0 * 8 = 0
0 * 4 = 0
0 * 2 = 0
0 * 1 = 0
```

Adding those together you get 3253408256

You an short cut that a bit by treating the original IP address as a base 256 number. So you have 0 units, 18 of 256s, 235 of 65536 (ie, 256 * 256) and 193 of (ie, 256 * 256 * 256)

**0** * 1 + **18** * 256 + **235** * 256 * 256 + **193** * 256 * 256 * 256

INET_ATON function that is mentioned does this for you.