# Sql query to get the row if user ip in between column[ipfrom and ipto] of database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database table alike

```
id   ipfrom    ito        country     code
1    1.0.0.0   1.0.0.255  Australia   AU
2    1.0.1.0   1.0.3.255  China       CN
```

I have multiple rows in table around 12500 data.

I need sql query to get the row if user ip in between ipfrom and ipto of any row.

Example:

If i request for ip - 1.0.0.1 then it must return first row as shown in above table.

**Updated:**

I am using mysql

Comment: Which DB do you use? Did you search for that in the net? There are useful articles like https://www.sisense.com/blog/comparing-ip-addresses-in-sql/, didn't they help?

Comment: I am using mysql

Comment: So this doesn't work?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24179437/mysql-check-if-an-ip-address-is-in-range